# If value in MYSQL is updated, other values changes

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to make that when the value of a MYSQL attribute is changed, other values ​​of other attributes also vary.

For example:

I have the color_scheme attribute with value "RED".
If the color_scheme value changes to "BLUE" the value of:

```
menu_color changes to #30618F
font_color changes to #FFFFFF
footer_color changes to #1A92CA
```

Is it possible?

And it must update the values only once, because users must be able to change specific atributes (like menu_color, font_color, footer_color) separately.

Just like this:

[image: Update values depending on other]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a table structure and some sample data?

Comment: Added image, i think it nails it.

Comment: Oke, how do you mean change? Do you mean random new color numbers or do you want a scheme to be loaded.

Comment: I want a scheme to be loaded

Comment: Oke, in that case you need a bridge table. With the schemes in it.

Comment: Where can i find some concrete info about it? Sorry, I have no idea what this is

Comment: I working on a example, but it will cost time to complete.

Comment: have you looked at my answer below?

Comment: Yes i did and thanks for the attention, but it looks like a manual changing, the codes are all in sql, i need it to be dinamic. I'm posting another screenshot to be more clear, take a look please

Comment: Which programming language are you using? PHP? Your question is tagged with mysql then you get a mysql answer, because I presume that you can implement it into your code.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to adept it to your situation, because I don't have your tables structure, sample data and your current PHP script.

Comment: The dynamic part is added by PHP. B.T.W. can you code PHP or are you using a CMS (Drupal, Wordpress, etc) and / or framework?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE color_scheme (
  id_color_sheme INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  color_esquema VARCHAR(30),
  color_front_banners VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_banners_bottom VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_botoes VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_links VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_menu VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_rodape VARCHAR(7),
  index(color_esquema) 
  );



CREATE TABLE user_interface (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  color_front_banners VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_banners_bottom VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_botoes VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_links VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_menu VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_rodape VARCHAR(7)


  );

-- SAMPLE DATA
INSERT INTO user_interface (
                          color_front_banners,
                          color_front_banners_bottom,
                         color_front_botoes,
                         color_front_links,
                         color_front_menu,
                         color_front_rodape)
VALUES ('#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF'),
('#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE') ; 



INSERT INTO color_scheme (color_esquema,
                          color_front_banners,
                          color_front_banners_bottom,
                         color_front_botoes,
                         color_front_links,
                         color_front_menu,
                         color_front_rodape)
VALUES ('black','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF'),
('grey','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE') ;

-- UPDATE based on color_esquema
SET @color_name := 'black'; 
UPDATE user_interface 
SET 
  color_front_banners = (
SELECT color_front_banners FROM color_scheme
WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),


  color_front_banners_bottom = (
SELECT color_front_banners_bottom FROM color_scheme
WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),

  color_front_botoes = (
SELECT color_front_botoes FROM color_scheme
WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),

  color_front_links = (
SELECT color_front_links FROM color_scheme
WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),

  color_front_menu = (
SELECT color_front_menu FROM color_scheme
WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),

  color_front_rodape = (
SELECT color_front_rodape FROM color_scheme
WHERE color_esquema = @color_name )

WHERE id = 2;

-- If you want to change just one color, you can use this query.
UPDATE user_interface 
SET 
  color_front_botoes = '#DDDDDD'
WHERE id = 1;
```

How does this work? First you create a table with the colors (e.g. 'color_scheme'). Then you get the values (e.g. 'blue','#....',...) from this table inserted into your 'user_interface' table.  BTW I made the assumption that you will use this for a user interface. Anyway you can adopted it for your needs. Important to note is that you can only update data that is first inserted into a database. So, you should start with default colors when a user is added. I would even recommend that you create a separate table with the colors, separate from the user table.

Next you want to update the default colors based on the selected color scheme. Lets say you want to use 'blue'. Then you should use an update query to update the values in the user_interface table (or colors table). The most basic way would be to do subqueries like I did with then says WHERE color_esquema = 'blue'. I added the set color_name variable to ease the entries. With this statement you started to declare a variable called color_name and you just need to declare it once a use it throughout you query. You can if you want to revert back insert your color_esquema name.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af117/1)

I first add grey colors to the last row in the user_interface. Then I use the update query to change the value into a new color schema which is black. To break it down into steps.

```
CREATE TABLE color_scheme (
  id_color_sheme INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  color_esquema VARCHAR(30),
  color_front_banners VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_banners_bottom VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_botoes VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_links VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_menu VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_rodape VARCHAR(7),
  index(color_esquema) 
  );



CREATE TABLE user_interface (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  color_front_banners VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_banners_bottom VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_botoes VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_links VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_menu VARCHAR(7),
  color_front_rodape VARCHAR(7)


  );

-- SAMPLE DATA
INSERT INTO user_interface (
                          color_front_banners,
                          color_front_banners_bottom,
                         color_front_botoes,
                         color_front_links,
                         color_front_menu,
                         color_front_rodape)
VALUES ('#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF'),
('#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE') ; 



INSERT INTO color_scheme (color_esquema,
                          color_front_banners,
                          color_front_banners_bottom,
                         color_front_botoes,
                         color_front_links,
                         color_front_menu,
                         color_front_rodape)
VALUES ('black','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF','#FFFFFF'),
('grey','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE','#EEEEEE') ;
```

[First step](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d912e/1)

Then the same data with the update. B.T.W. fiddle doesn't allow me to do this in right 
panel. See final at the top.

[Second step](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af117/1)

**PHP**

A PHP script to change the color scheme.

```
    <?php

    $color_name = 'black';

    $host = 'host';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = 'password';
    $database = 'database';

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    IF (!$link) {
        echo ('Unable to connect to database');
    }
    ELSE{
        $query = "
            SET @color_name := '".$color_name."'; 
    UPDATE user_interface 
    SET 
      color_front_banners = (
    SELECT color_front_banners FROM color_scheme
    WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),


      color_front_banners_bottom = (
    SELECT color_front_banners_bottom FROM color_scheme
    WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),

      color_front_botoes = (
    SELECT color_front_botoes FROM color_scheme
    WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),

      color_front_links = (
    SELECT color_front_links FROM color_scheme
    WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),

      color_front_menu = (
    SELECT color_front_menu FROM color_scheme
    WHERE color_esquema = @color_name ),

      color_front_rodape = (
    SELECT color_front_rodape FROM color_scheme
    WHERE color_esquema = @color_name )

    WHERE id = 2;
            ";
        mysqli_query($link, $query);
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>

**Edit Wordpress udpate **
```

This will only load the color scheme names:

```
   <?php
// insert database connection to get the colors from the color scheme 
   function retrieve_color_scheme() {
       $host = 'host';
       $user = 'user';
       $password = 'password';
       $database = 'database';

       $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
       IF (!$link) {
           echo ('Unable to connect to database');
       } ELSE {
           $query = "SELECT color_esquema FROM color_scheme";
           $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
           $choices = mysql_fetch_array($result);
           return $choices;
       }
       mysqli_close($link);
   }


                    $this->add_control( 'color_esquema', array(
                            'label'   => 'Esquema de cores:',
                            'section' => 'custom_colors',
                            'type'    => 'select',
                            'priority'=> 9,
                            'choices'    => retrieve_color_scheme()
                    ) );                

                    $this->add_setting( 'color_menu', array(
                            'default'        => '#65696E',
                            'type'           => 'option',
                            'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
                            'transport'      => 'postMessage',
                            'priority'       => 10
                    ) );

                    $this->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $this, 'color_menu', array(
                            'label'   => __( 'Fundo do Menu'),
                            'section' => 'custom_colors',
                            'settings'   => 'color_menu',
                            'priority'       => 10
                    ) ) );

                    $this->add_setting( 'color_titulo_menu', array(
                            'default'        => '#FFFFFF',
                            'type'           => 'option',
                            'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
                            'transport'      => 'postMessage',
                            'priority'       => 15
                    ) );

                    $this->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $this, 'color_titulo_menu', array(
                            'label'   => __( 'T&iacute;tulo'),
                            'section' => 'custom_colors',
                            'settings'   => 'color_titulo_menu',
                            'priority'       => 15
                    ) ) );                
?>                   
    <!-- Page -->
    <?php $color_menu = get_option('color_menu');  ?>
    <?php $color_titulo_menu = get_option('color_titulo_menu');?>

        #container{border-top:82px solid <?php if(empty($color_menu)){echo "#65696E";} else { echo "$color_menu";}; ?>}
        #logo a span{color:<?php if(empty($color_titulo_menu)){echo "#FFFFFF";} else { echo "$color_titulo_menu";}; ?>}

    <!-- My try - In Page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement for this. This is a pretty simplified version, but this should get you on the right track.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET menu_color = CASE WHEN color_scheme = 'Red' THEN '#30618F' WHEN color_scheme = 'Blue' THEN  '#FFFFFF' ELSE '' END
```

Comment: But how do i make that it update only once? I wanna first change the color scheme then the other attributes are changed. But after that i wanna be able to change each attribute separately without it reseting to it color_scheme default value.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `color_schemes` table and store the details for each color scheme there.

Answer (score 0):

Radical,

I'm Artur's friend, I tried a different aproach for this same problem yesterday, and I don't know if it's easier or what... [Please take a look at my other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90070/using-color-schemes-with-color-picker)

We are using Wordpress, and we are not very good at coding PHP, we can adapt scripts and stuff, but we are not very good at creating our own.

Thank you for your efforts, we are almost there!

Comment: The approach to use a array is good when you a small number of themes. The more themes you will use the easier it will become to use mysql to store the colors. If you post the complete form page I can perhaps give you more help.

Comment: It think the page I will need is customize.php. This page will contain the form where you select the color scheme or use to specify a specific color. Not sure but if guess you want to change all the colors below when you select a different color scheme. That would require that the form method is set to post and action to PHP_SELF or the customize.php. Furthermore, you will need my SQL query to get the colors from the database and display them.

Comment: I made a pastebin with some arrays and how we call them on the page, because it would be too big and many unrelated stuff to post everything here, so please, take a look:

http://pastebin.com/agUuPsnq

Comment: This is what makes customizing a CMS so difficult. The code you have provided is only half what I need. I see no form with a submit button. No way to tell how the color data gets inside the form. The controllers classes that are used are not found in your document. How they work is therefore a complete mystery. There are basically two ways you can solve this. Try to find out how WP works internally or to work around WP.

Comment: I have added the WP tag.  Maybe another person how knows how WP works can help you out. The best of luck.